# BASH : Problem regarding hash table/dictionary and bad substitution

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi

**Context:**
I started writing this script for easily changing connections for my raspberry pi zero (Raspibian Lite as OS), this is because I always needed to edit the wpa-supplicant config file and decided to do something about it as it is a really portable pc.

**How it works:**
The core of the program is to create profiles in format of dictionaries to store the name and passwd and apply that profile when needed. **The profiles are added to the script code itself.** I made it like this, every time a new profile is created this 2 lines are generated with the profile name corresponded. For example:

`declare -A profile1` 
`profile1=( ["name"]="name" ["pass"]="pass")`

**Problem:**
To apply that profile I put at terminal prompt "./script --use profile1" so my goal is that it gets the details of the profile desired.
When I write that by :

`echo "${$2[name]}"` it outputs me a " bad substitution" error.

**Things I tried and checked:**

- Shebang is #!/bin/bash
- I tried substituting the $2 in a string and trying to execute it but I dont get anything good.

**Things to consider:**

- Here is the link to the script so you can test it yourself, there are some things are a bit more complex than the thing indicated in the post but I just simplified it.
  https://github.com/gugeldot23/wpa_scrip

Comment: I have to thank anyone who has time to help me, appreciate it. This's my very first question over here. Have a good day!

Comment: `this 2 lines are generated` Why not one line? `declare -A profile1=( ["name"]="name" ["pass"]="pass")` would be clearer. You script seem to have many beginners mistakes - use http://shellcheck.net to find most simple shell mistakes.

Comment: Sure I could put it in 2 lines I just wanted to get it in a way I could look it easily while testing , as you could see my code is somehow a mess xD. Anyways thanks for the page for checking mistakes its quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need nameref variables if you want to address the profile array name by reference:

```sh
declare -n profile # nameref variable profile

profile="$2" # Fills-in the nameref from argument 2

# Address the nameref instead of echo "${$2[name]}"
echo "${profile[name]}"
```

See: [gnu.org Bash Manual / Bash Builtins / `declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins):

> `-n`
>
> Give each name the nameref attribute, making it a name reference to another variable. That other variable is defined by the value of name. All references, assignments, and attribute modifications to name, except for those using or changing the `-n` attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by name’s value. The nameref attribute cannot be applied to array variables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It works and I read the page. Really useful